# Unexpected behaviour when navigating through webpages using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I want to navigate through all the continents/ countries [here](https://www.ertms.net/deployment-world-map/) and collect the tables into a pandas data frame, but sometimes the process clicks on the same link a couple of times before continuing on to the next. This is my current implementation:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
DRIVER_PATH = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.ertms.net/deployment-world-map/')

continents = driver.find_element(by='id', value='panel')
continent_names = continents.text.split()

# navigating through continent links
for i, cont in enumerate(continent_names):
    cont_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
    continent_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(cont_buttons[i + 1]))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(continent_element).click().perform()

    time.sleep(3)
    child_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
    
    # going through country links for each continent. Here is where the same link is sometimes clicked twice
    for j, country in enumerate(child_buttons):
        time.sleep(3)
        child_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
        country_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(child_buttons[j]))

        time.sleep(0.5)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(country_element).click().perform()
        
        # going back to page with list of countries for current continent
        back_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('go-back')

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", back_button)
        time.sleep(3)

    # going back to list of continents
    back_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('go-back')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", back_button)
    time.sleep(3)
```

I navigate around using `EC.element_to_be_clickable` and a combination of the `By.LINK_TEXT` or `find_elements_by_class_name` methods. Any advice on best practices would be appreciated.

Comment: `but sometimes the process clicks on the same link a couple of times before continuing on to the next. ` - Update the question with relevant code. Going through all the code IMP is a tedious job.

Comment: Updated, the problem lies in the j-for loop going through the countries